# How can i fix the following gmp library dependency error while trying to install Charm?

Tags: python, libraries, dependencies

I am trying to install Charm crypto python framework in ubuntu 11.04 with python 2.7.
Requirements say that i should have gmp installed 5.*. I have successfully installed gmp lib and i have run all the tests. Also after running `

```
ldconfig -p |grep libgmp

libgmpxx.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so.4
libgmpxx.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so
libgmp.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10
libgmp.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3
libgmp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so
libgmp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgmp.so
```

In order to install Charm i have downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/releases/download/v0.43/Charm-Crypto-0.43_Python3.tar.gz). I run `./configure, make , make install`, and `sdconfig` as the INSTALL says.

But after running make test for i am getting a lot of errors of this form:

```
charm/Charm-Crypto-0.43/charm/core/math/integer.so: undefined symbol: __gmpz_powm_sec
```

Charm shared libraries cannot find libgmp. How can i fix that?
I made an ldd integer.so and it uses libgmp.so.3. In my system libgmp.so.3 is placed under /usr/lib so added this line under te config.mk file of the Charm framework:

```
LDFLAGS= -m64 -L/usr/lib .
```

(-m64 was already there). I `make` and `make install` again but i am getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

It might be just you didn't install the dev lib for gmp, try:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

Then re-do configure/make/etc. for Charm

Comment: I have already installed it. The correct name is `libgmp3-dev`

Comment: @curious Charm required libgmp 5, libgmp3-dev is only for libgmp 3

Comment: but making an ldd to integer.so that causes most of the problems i see that it is linked ton libgmp3.so : `ldd integer.so 
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff347ff000)
 libgmp.so.3 => /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3 (0x00007fd4b9014000)
 libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00007fd4b8c85000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd4b8a66000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd4b86ce000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd4b84ca000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 
 
`

Comment: also there is no libgmp5-dev package

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue while building mpfr. My `libgmp.so` was in `/usr/local/lib`. Running the folowing command solved the issue:

```
sudo ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
```

Alternatively you can edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` and add `lib` dir path here or just copy all files from `/usr/local/lib` to `/usr/lib`.